# Iterate over a task model, counting users, ...then remove any user who exists more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, find, loops

I need to evaluate if a user_id exists more than once in an array.  Ultimately, I need to determine if a user was able to complete a task (each task is saved as a record) in one attempt.  I need to display a percentage of success, which is ultimately determined by the number of users who get it right on the first try.  I added a boolean to the task model ':passed', but then I have to write more logic to set that boolean for the first record, and then unset it if any subsequent record is created.  That smells.  My approach now is to simply create an array of task.users, then determine if any user_id exists in that array more than once...and if it does remove all instances of that integer from the array (so that they are not counted).  I'm tripping over my own thought process and not having success...

How can I iterate over all tasks and count each iterations user_id and .delete(user_id) of any user whos count is > 1?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your example above but I can't quite get it. Could you provide more information or attempt to clarify? Also this sounds like a data-modeling issue. How married are you to your current schema?

Comment: Thanks.  For example if I use task.users.map(&:user_id).uniq I will remove all duplicates and only return unique values of user_id.  However, what I want to do is...if any user_id value is found in the array more than once remove that user_id completely from the array

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand what you're asking, but this will give you an array of user_id's that have completed the task without duplicates:

```
task.users.map(&:user_id).uniq
```

Based on your comment you can try:

```
task.users.group_by{ |u| u.user_id }.collect{ |u, dups| u if dups.size == 1 }.compact
```

Comment: If a user_id shows up twice (more than once) I need it to be gone from the array completely (all instances of it).  Your example would remove duplicates but leave one uniq value behind...but what Im looking for is if a duplicate exists...remove all instances of that user_id from the array.